# Excel Formula Not Recognizing Non Text value

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Formula below gives me a `#VALUE!` error.

`=IF(AND(CELL("type",C163)="v",C163+1<=$D$4), C163+1,"-")`

I'm scrolling down a column to populate cells in sequence, all based on numerical values. All works well BUT when a cell becomes a dash, according to the formula, then the next cell below that dash cell gives the `#VALUE!` error. My formula struggles to understand what to do with the dash. I believe the problem is in the second logical of the `AND`. i.e. `C163+1<=$D$4`. The first logical `CELL("type",C163)="v"` is just asking if the cell above contains a numerical value and it works OK, in isolation, but things break down with the second logical. Any ideas? The cell after the dash cell should also be dashed.

Comment: Why Cell() and not ISNUMBER()?

Comment: `ISNUMBER` I tried as the first logical and it works in isolation like `Cell()` but the second logical breaks down in the same way. Hence either way, the second logical I believe is the problem. That little part of the formula isn't dealing well with a cell that contains a non numerical value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If C163 is not a number then `C163+1` will fail.  Nest the IF instead

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(C163),IF(C163+1<=$D$4,C163+1,"-"),"-")
```

this way only numbers are tested.

Comment: Scott that's what I was playing with...Nested IFs. And you got it. It works. Thankyou!